# \bfseries not working

Tags: fonts

I have using a CV template from the web to make my CV and it worked just fine up till now. However, today without me making any font changes it suddenly won't show any bold fonts. For instance for the CV heading I use

```
\newcommand{\cvheading}[1]{{\Huge\bfseries\color{RoyalBlue} #1} \\[-6pt]} % New command for the CV heading
```

The `\bfseries` just does not seem to work. I tried changing the color from `RoyalBlue` to `Red` and that worked, so am definitely looking at the correct part of the code.

Any clues why this may be happening would be helpful.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  It’s difficult to answer your question with the information you provide.  “Does not seem to work” doesn’t mean anything: what happens exactly?  Do you get error messages?  What do they say?  You should also include a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/69818) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: In case you think the problem is related to the template you are using, please be a bit more specific than "from the web", there are probably trillions of templates out there.

Comment: You have to load the `xcolor` package with either the `svgnames` or `dvipsnames` option (both also works).

Comment: I can see a bold heading. Since you say it happened suddenly, you have (maybe unaware) changed the code.

Comment: the `\\ ` at the end of the heading _must_ be an error most likely producing underfull hbox badness 10000 warnings?

Comment: Right now, all i can say is: I can see bold font compiling with the unchanged template. You have changed something, which we (and you right now) are not aware of. You have to search for it and show it to us. Right now, your question cannot be ansered.

Comment: I can identify the template and bold font works just as expected. The OP has done something strange, what exactly is unknown to us. In its current state, the question cannot be answered. I vote to close as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\cvheading}[1]{{\Huge\bfseries\color{RoyalBlue} #1} \\[-6pt]} % New command for the CV heading

\begin{document}
    \cvheading{hello}
\end{document}
```

Wild guess: the font you're using doesn't have a matching bold version.

Comment: ... or maybe in OP's template `RoyalBlue` is an alias for `BoldFontDestroyingRoyalBlue` whereas `Red` maps to `WeightPreservingRed`.  ;-) +1

Comment: Maybe ;)))))))))